# Type of sentence/correct usage

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, british-english

> It makes you consider the  difference between riding down that road in
>   a car, versus driving down that road on a bicycle.

What do we call these type of clauses, where they have a comparative meaning/contrast?

Is the comma here accurate or optional; what is the main clause?

Comment: I drive a car and ride a bicycle. It seems very odd to use the verbs the other way round.